# How to recover a .txt file from an image of a damaged external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, text

I have an old external hard drive that is recognized by Ubuntu but doesn't show the files (just one empty folder and I can't create anything on it)

I went through this, and was able to create an image of the drive with ddrescue.Then using formost on the image file I was able to recover most of my files.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

However formost doesn't recover .txt files. I also tried Magic Rescue and ntfsundelete which didn't work. Any idea how I can recover txt files from this image or damaged external hard drive?

```
$ mmls image 
Cannot determine partition type
```

Comment: You can try to mount the image (as described in the "Extract filesystem from recovered image" section from your link) and then use TestDisk to try to recover the files, see here: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_FAQ. Text files cannot be recovered by automatic "scanning" tools like foremost or photorec because there's no way to identify them amongst the other data (it doesn't have a "header" that's always the same, for a recovery tool that's scanning the image to stop and realize "hey, this is a text file" and recover it. It's just.. text.

Comment: Hence the only tools that could potentially recover the text file are ones that read the actual partitions and file table information (ntfsundelete, TestDisk..), which then points to where on the image / disk the text file is. If that doesn't work, _and_ you know some of the text that's in the file, you can try to manually scan the disk image with something like `strings diskimage.img | grep -B 5 -A 5 "known text"` - i haven't tried that particular command, but the basic idea is to search the image file for the known text and then extract the rest of the sourrounding text with some other tool.